# how to call a function every several millisecond using coroutine in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I want to get request to network every 3 seconds and in the some condition stop it. I am using `Coroutine` for network request.I used `postDelayed()` method and it work correctly. But I want to make the next request after previous response of the previous request is complete.I used `delay` method of `Coroutine` but But The UI have freeze and My app is remained in the infinite loop .How to handle this task using `postDelayed` or coroutine? I create network request in the this repository:

```
     class ProcessRepository  @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) {
    val _networkState = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()
    val _networkState_first = MutableLiveData<NetworkState>()

    val completableJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + completableJob)

    private val brokerProcessResponse = MutableLiveData<BrokerProcessResponse>()
 fun repeatRequest(processId:String):MutableLiveData<BrokerProcessResponse>{
        var networkState = NetworkState(Status.LOADING, userMessage)
        _networkState.postValue(networkState)
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val request = apiService.repeatRequest(processId, token)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                try {
                    val response = request.await()
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        brokerProcessResponse.postValue(response.body())
                        var networkState = NetworkState(Status.SUCCESS, userMessage)
                        _networkState.postValue(networkState)
                    } else {
                        var networkState = NetworkState(Status.ERROR, userMessage)
                        _networkState.postValue(networkState)
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    var networkState = NetworkState(Status.ERROR, userMessage)
                    _networkState.postValue(networkState)
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    var networkState = NetworkState(Status.ERROR, userMessage)
                    _networkState.postValue(networkState)
                }
            }
            delay(3000) // I only just add this line for try solution using coroutine 
        }

        return brokerProcessResponse
    }
```

And this is code in my fragment:

```
     private fun repeatRequest(){
        viewModel.repeatRequest(processId).observe(this, Observer {

                if(it!=null){
                    process=it.process
                    if(it.process.state== FINDING_BROKER || it.process.state==NONE){
                        inProgress(true)
                    }else{
                        inProgress(false)
                 }
                    setState(it!!.process.state!!,it.process)
                }

        })
    }
 private fun pullRequest(){
        while (isPullRequest){
            repeatRequest()
        }

    }
```

And My solution using `postDelayed`:

```
     private fun init() {
        mHandler = Handler()
}


private fun pullRequest() {

        mRunnable = Runnable {

            repeatRequest()
            Log.e(TAG, "in run")
            mHandler.postDelayed(
                mRunnable,
                3000
            )
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(
            mRunnable,
            3000
        )
    }
 private fun cancelRequest() {
    viewModel.cancelRequest(processId).observe(this, Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            processShareViewModel.setProcess(it.process)
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

            isPullRequest = false
            if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.requstBrokerFragment) {
                val nextAction = RequstBrokerFragmentDirections.actionRequstBrokerFragmentToHomeFragment()
                // nextAction.keyprocess = it.process
                findNavController().navigate(nextAction)
            }

        }
        Log.e(TAG, "response request borker: " + it.toString())
    })
}


 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Stop the periodic task
        isPullRequest = false
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who are  new to Coroutine

add Coroutine in Build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
```

Add a repeating Job

```
    /**
     * start Job
     * val job = startRepeatingJob()
     * cancels the job and waits for its completion
     * job.cancelAndJoin()
     * Params
     * timeInterval: time milliSeconds 
     */
    private fun startRepeatingJob(timeInterval: Long): Job {
        return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            while (NonCancellable.isActive) {
                // add your task here
                doSomething()
                delay(timeInterval)
            }
        }
    }
```

To start:

```
  Job myJob = startRepeatingJob(1000L)
```

To Stop:

```
    myJob .cancel()
```

Answer (score 6):

Your UI is freezing because your `while` loop is running without a break:

```
while (isPullRequest){
     repeatRequest()
}
```

Your are starting a coroutine asynchronously in `repeatRequest` and invoke `delay` there. This will not suspend the `pullRequest` function.

You should run the loop within the coroutine (`repeatRequest` function). Then you can give the `job` object of this coroutine to the caller and invoke `cancel` whenever you like to stop the loop:

```
fun repeatRequest(): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch {  
        while(isActive) {
            //do your request
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
}

//start the loop
val repeatJob = repeatRequest()

//Cancel the loop
repeatJob.cancel()
```

Comment: how to define `coroutineScope` variable?

Comment: The same way like you `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + completableJob)`

Comment: Is your solution satisfy this condition? ''I want to make the next request after previous response of the previous request is complete.''

Comment: Yes, if the request in the loop is blocking until the result has arrived. If the request in the loop  is asynchronous, then not.

Comment: How to restart my job after canceling it? When I cancel the `repeatRequest()` job,it did not cancel and my loop is continue and I have to cancel `completableJob` and when call `completableJob.start()`, My job did not restart.

Comment: I just tested this sample code: https://gist.github.com/rpreissel/84ef62a41abd5dfd78e42fc865a60a88. And the repeat job doos stop. And it is possible to call the function `repeatRequest` to restart the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927627/how-to-break-from-lambda-passed-to-recursive-function-when-provided-condition-mate), it has a custom `loop` and it's usage can look like this

```
    // if loop block takes less than 3 seconds, then this loop will iterate after every 3 seconds
    // if loop block takes more than 3 seconds, then this loop will iterate after block is finished
    // loop iterate after block duration or provided minimum interval whichever is maximum
    loop(3.seconds) {
     // make request
     // process response

     stopIf(condition)
    }
```