# how to break from lambda passed to recursive function when provided condition met

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am writing a custom `loop` dsl and I want it's usage to look like below

```
    var counter1 = 0
    var counter2 = 0
    loop {
            counter1 += 1
            println(counter1)
            stopIf(counter1 == 5) // loop should terminate here and not execute rest of the code if condition matches

            counter2 += 2
            println(counter2)
            stopIf(counter2 == 8) // loop should terminate here and not execute rest of the code if condition matches

        }
```

I have following code which does allows me to write `stopIf` any number of times and anywhere in the `loop` body but when condition matches it does not terminate immediately but executes rest of the loop body and then terminates.

```
    @UseExperimental(ExperimentalTime::class)
    open class Loop {
        var stop = false

        val loopInterval = 1.seconds

        suspend fun loop(block: suspend () -> Unit): Unit = loop(loopInterval, block)

        suspend fun loop(minimumInterval: Duration, block: suspend () -> Unit): Unit =
            loopWithoutDelay { delayedResult(maxOf(minimumInterval, loopInterval), block) }

        private suspend fun loopWithoutDelay(block: suspend () -> Unit) {
            block()
            if (stop) return else loopWithoutDelay(block)
        }

        suspend fun <T> delayedResult(minDelay: Duration, f: suspend () -> T): T = coroutineScope {
            val futureValue = async { f() }
            delay(minDelay.toJavaDuration())
            futureValue.await()
        }

        fun stopIf(condition: Boolean) {
            if (condition) {
                stop = condition // once stop condition matches, then do not override it with following false condtions
            }
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalTime
    suspend fun loop(block: suspend Loop.() -> Unit) =
        Loop().run { loop { block(this) } }
```

I have tried to use `return` with `label` but it did not work. **Is there any way I can achieve this?**

Answer (score 2):

It can be done for example with throwing a lightweight exception. You have to declare custom exception:

```
class LoopStopException : Throwable("Stop look", null, false, false) // lightweight throwable without the stack trace
```

and catch it in `loopWithoutDelay`:

```
private suspend fun loopWithoutDelay(block: suspend () -> Unit) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            block()
        }
    } catch (e: LoopStopException) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, never thought about it.
Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand much about the function `delayedResult`, because none of the dsl's public functions return a result. However, I come up with an solution for cancelling the loop.

As far as I understood, we have to have a loop that doesn't block the current thread. Therefore, it must be run in a coroutine, but in order to be able to cancel the loop, the dsl must run its own coroutine. This inner coroutine is run using `coroutineScope`, so it suspends the parent coroutine until it's finished or cancelled.

```
@ExperimentalTime
class Loop {
    private val loopInterval = 1.seconds

    suspend fun loop(block: suspend () -> Unit) = loop(loopInterval, block)

    suspend fun loop(minimumInterval: Duration, block: suspend () -> Unit):Job  = coroutineScope {
        launch {
            while (true) {
                block()
                delay(minOf(minimumInterval, loopInterval).toLongMilliseconds())
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun stopIf(condition: Boolean) = coroutineScope {
        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> {
            if (condition) it.cancel() else it.resumeWith(Result.success(Unit))
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalTime
suspend fun loop(block: suspend Loop.() -> Unit):Job {
    return Loop().run {
        this.loop {
            block(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost covers all the use cases but if I have a code after `stopIf` which is not `coroutine`, then that gets executed for ex. `println`